# Embed Variable in href mailto link

Tags: html

Good day,

We are currently making use of Mimecast to tag stationary on the outgoing emails. In Mimecast you can sync attributes from Active Directory for use in personalized email signatures, etc.
I am currently trying to configure a mailto link that uses the "Display Name" attribute in the link, to add the senders name to the subject of the email.

However I cannot get to work. Also in the Mimecast HTML editor no var variables can be passed as it only allows basic HTML.

The Mimecast attribute for display name is pulled with the following piece of code...

```
<mc type="variable" source="from" attribute="displayName">
```

This needs to replace "FirstName%20LastName" in the code below.

```
<a   href="mailto:recipient@company.com?subject=FirstName%20LastName%20-%20Exceeded%20Expectations" target="_blank"><mc type="clickimage" code="imagebottomleft"></a>
```

Kind regards,

Renier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the [specification (RFC2368)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), and it does not seem that this feature exists.

Comment: That is my interpretation, yes.

Comment: Thanks Evert, Do you perhaps know of possible workaround I can try?